# ListView modify other view from specific view

Tags: android

I have a ListView that contains 5 rows with 5 button:

[image]

When I click on first button, I replace it text with "B".

[image]

Then, I click on second button, I replace it text with "B", but how can I replace the previous clicked button (the first) with "A"?

[image]

This is what really happen:

[image]

This is my code for the button click:

```
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewHolder holder;
private Context ctx;
public RingtoneAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Ringtone> objects) {
    super(context, resourceId, objects);
    this.ctx = context;
    resource = resourceId;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Recuperiamo l'oggetti che dobbiamo inserire a questa posizione
    final Ringtone ringtone = getItem(position);

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.btnPlay = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Button btnadd = (Button) view;
            btnadd.setText("B");
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return v;
}
private static class ViewHolder {
    Button btnPlay;
    TextView txtTitolo;
    TextView txtCategoria;
}
```

Comment: you should have to modify data set of ListView not actual button, please upload your Adapter so I can suggest better

Comment: I updated with my adapter class

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a ListView instead of say a RadioGroup?

Comment: My row is more complex than what I drawed. It contains also other element such as TextView. The number of rows is not fixed but it depends from database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you only want a single position to be 'selected' at a time. If that's the case, you could keep a reference to the selected position, and use the Adapter's functionality instead of having multiple buttons know about each other. e.g.

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    // ... Your ViewHolder / Ringtone initialization

    if(position == selectedPosition)
        holder.btnPlay.setText("B");
    else holder.btnPlay.setText("A");

    holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        if(holder.btnPlay.getText().toString().equals("A")) 
            selectedPosition = position;
        else selectedPosition = -1;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The key here is allowing `notifyDataSetChanged()` to internally call your getView method, which then really only needs to know how to render the data in its current state, instead of dealing with the complex logic required to map between multiple Views.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if I click on the same button twice I would like it text is "A" again. How could I do this?

Comment: You could just check the current text of the clicked View. I updated the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset the items which were not clicked,

```
 btn.setText("B"); // if the item was clicked

 btn.setText("A"); // for all other items
```

what you can do is, cycle through all elements setting the text for button like this `btn.setText("A")`, once this is done call `btn.setText("B")`

you should be using `OnItemClickListener` on the `listview`, it is easy that way, as you are setting the value in view holder, it does not give you access to the other items in the `listview`, but by using `OnItemClickListener` you can cover all the elements in the `listview` once you update things as you like call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, As this can be done there is another way to look at the problem

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewTestSevenActivity_listView);
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Item item = new Item("A");
        items.add(item);
    }
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This will take care of initialization and rest of the code as you want it to work. code is also available on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/listview/test/activities/ListviewTestSevenActivity.java)

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context a_context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater a_layoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.a_context = context;
        this.items = items;
        a_layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.a_context);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            row = a_layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_listview_seven, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewTestSevenActivity_text_button);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Item item = items.get(position);
        System.out.println("" + item.getText());

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (Item current_item : items) {
                    current_item.setText("A");
                }
                item.setText("B");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        holder.button.setText("" + item.getText());
        return row;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        Button button;
    }
}

private class Item {
    String text;

    public Item(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I access my button in OnItemClickListener in the activity?

Comment: @aletede91, ok i have written some snippet that might help you get the idea, as you already solved it